# Two column page with vertically centered content and image slide in one column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a *simple* landingpage with 2 full height columns where one of the columns consists of a responsive image slide. I understand that since the page is split into halves i need to have images which are taller than wider (not a problem). Furthermore i want the content (text, etc.) to be vertically centered in the columns as well.

What i have achieved so far is creating two columns, where content is centered but the image slide on the column is not behaving correctly, as it is not initialized as a full-size background that covers the entire column, which is where i do not know how to solve this issue.

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.slider_container img {
    -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
    -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
    -o-background-size: 100% auto;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display:none;
    visibility: visible;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index:10;
    position: fixed;
}
.vcenter {
    min-height: 100%;
    /* Fallback for vh unit */
    min-height: 100vh;
    /* You might also want to use
    'height' property instead.

    Note that for percentage values of
    'height' or 'min-height' properties,
    the 'height' of the parent element
    should be specified explicitly.

    In this case the parent of '.vertical-center'
    is the <body> element */
    /* Make it a flex container */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    /* Align the bootstrap's container vertically */
    -webkit-box-align : center;
    -webkit-align-items : center;
    -moz-box-align : center;
    -ms-flex-align : center;
    align-items : center;
    /* In legacy web browsers such as Firefox 9
    we need to specify the width of the flex container */
    width: 100%;
    /* Also 'margin: 0 auto' doesn't have any effect on flex items in such web browsers
    hence the bootstrap's container won't be aligned to the center anymore.

    Therefore, we should use the following declarations to get it centered again */
    -webkit-box-pack : center;
    -moz-box-pack : center;
    -ms-flex-pack : center;
    -webkit-justify-content : center;
    justify-content : center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="vcenter">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
             <h1>This is a split page</h1>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 slider_container">
             <h1>This is a image slide</h1>

            <img src="http://www.h3dwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Tall_building-8.jpg" />
            <img src="http://kuaibozz.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/tall-building-amazing-ideas-1-on-building-simple-home-design.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cjy3aprw/1/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would use a different approach to create the columns. There is an actual column property which can be used like so:

```css
html,body,.row{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.row{
  -webkit-columns: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-columns: 2; /* Firefox */
  columns: 2;
  overflow-x: hidden; /*to remove some weird horizontal spacing after the element*/
}
@media (max-width:700px){
  .row{
    -webkit-columns: 1; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-columns: 1; /* Firefox */
    columns: 1;
  }
}
.row div{
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
}
.row div p{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  position:relative;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  text-align:center;
  z-index:2;
}
.row div img{
  width: auto;
  min-width:100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <p>Content left</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slider">
    <p>Content right</p>
    <img src="http://www.h3dwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Tall_building-8.jpg" />
    <img src="http://kuaibozz.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/tall-building-amazing-ideas-1-on-building-simple-home-design.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I presumed `.slider` was for Bootstrap or something so I left it in there, regardless I'm sure you can figure out how to change things from here. Hope this helps!

Comment: I like this approach. The only two problems i have with this is (1) the image is not responsive and (2) the columns do not collapse upon resizing (especially for mobile first functionality). Bootstrap is not a must, as i barely use any of its functionalities except the mobile first grid. And the slider class is only there for the slider image class and JS function.

Comment: Okay I've used a media query to make the columns collapse, I've used a max-size query here just to show it off, simply swap this to `@media handheld` and it should still be fine. Ngl I don't really know what you mean by the images not being responsive, could you please clarify?  Ah okay thought as much :)

Comment: Thats cool! What i mean by responsive images is proportional resizing so the image is not resized wrong.

Comment: Hmm okay, I thought that having 100% width and height would be better because half the image would be hidden or there would be empty space in the container. Regardless, I updated my answer with what I think you mean by responsive.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. I am trying to fill the column with one image (backgorund) and resizing it in a responsive way while still filling that column with the entire image. I know that this will crop the images regardless of the device, but the most important thing is that the image actual fills the entire column with as much image as possible.

Comment: Okay, gave it one last shot. If this isn't correct then I'm the wrong person for the job: not done this before sorry :/

Comment: This is extremely close to what i want to achieve. But if you take the page and begin to reduce the width or height it is trying to maintain 100% in width and height which makes the image become deformed in an uproportional way. I already have a lot of problems with doing this kind of responsive backgrounds while also obeying the proportions of the image. It is doing what i want, which is filling the column with the image, but the second problem is window sizes, which can destroy the image.